# AngularJS Jasmine writing testing code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I am a newbie to unit-testing and I am trying to write tests for my loginController:

```
function loginController($scope, $state, authService) {
    $scope.loginData = {
        userName: "",
        password: ""
    };
    $scope.message = "";

    $scope.login = function () {
        authService.login($scope.loginData).then(
            function (response) {},
            function (err) {
                $scope.message = err.error_description;
            });
        };

//-----Load----------------------------------------

    if (authService.authentication.isAuth) {
        if ($scope.$stateChangeStart != null && $scope.$stateChangeStart.length > 0) {
                //$scope.message = "testing2";
                $state.transitionTo($scope.$stateChangeStart[$scope.$stateChangeStart.length - 1].toState, $scope.$stateChangeStart[$scope.$stateChangeStart.length - 1].toParams);
            } else {
               // $scope.message = "testing";
                $state.transitionTo('home');
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

I am trying to test the load code if user is login redirect to the last know state.  I am getting a fail on the last `expect($state.transitionTo).toHaveBeenCalledWith($scope.$stateChangeStart[$scope.$stateChangeStart.length - 2].toState, $scope.$stateChangeStart[$scope.$stateChangeStart.length - 2].toParams);`.

Which it doesn't make sense to me. When i uncomment `expect($state.transitionTo).toHaveBeenCalledWith('home');` and comment out the last `expect($state.transitionTo).toHaveBeenCalledWith($scope.$stateChangeStart[$scope.$stateChangeStart.length - 2].toState, $scope.$stateChangeStart[$scope.$stateChangeStart.length - 2].toParams);` then the test passed. Any idea why?

Here is my test:

```
it('should redirect to last state when login in', function () {
        setAuthentication();
        spyOn($state, 'transitionTo').andCallThrough();
        var controller = createController();
        $httpBackend.flush();

        expect($authService.authentication.isAuth).toBe(true);
        expect($scope.$stateChangeStart).not.toBe(null);
        expect($scope.$stateChangeStart.length > 0).toBeTruthy();
        //expect($state.transitionTo).toHaveBeenCalledWith('home');
        expect($state.transitionTo).toHaveBeenCalledWith($scope.$stateChangeStart[$scope.$stateChangeStart.length - 1].toState, $scope.$stateChangeStart[$scope.$stateChangeStart.length - 1].toParams);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I has to flush the change to authService:

This test pass now:

```
it('should redirect to last state when login in', function () {
    setAuthentication();
    $httpBackend.flush(); 
    spyOn($state, 'transitionTo').andCallThrough();
    var controller = createController();

    expect($authService.authentication.isAuth).toBe(true);
    expect($scope.$stateChangeStart).not.toBe(null);
    expect($scope.$stateChangeStart.length > 0).toBeTruthy();
    //expect($state.transitionTo).toHaveBeenCalledWith('home');
    expect($state.transitionTo).toHaveBeenCalledWith($scope.$stateChangeStart[$scope.$stateChangeStart.length - 1].toState, $scope.$stateChangeStart[$scope.$stateChangeStart.length - 1].toParams);
});
```